# How to write linq query in Entity Framework but my table includes foreign key?

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, entity-framework, c#-3.0

I have a table it includes 3 foreign key field like that:

My Table:
**Kartlar**

- ID  (Pkey)
- RehberID  (Fkey)
- KampanyaID  (Fkey)
- BrimID (Fkey)
- Name
- Detail

How can i write entity query with linq :?

```
select * from Kartlar where RehberID=123 and KampanyaID=345 and BrimID=567
```

BUT please be careful I can not see RehberID, KampanyaID, BrimID in entity they are foreign keys. I should use entity key but how?

### My Entity:

Addding data into kartlar Table (RehberID, KampanyaID, BrimID) is ok. But which Kart'ID created? I need to learn which Id created after adding data (RehberID,KampanyaID,BrimID) into Kartlar?

```
public static List<Kartlar> SaveKartlar(int RehberID, int KampanyaID, int BrimID, string Notlar)
{
    using (GenSatisModuleEntities genSatisCtx = new GenSatisModuleEntities())
    {
       Kartlar kartlar = new Kartlar();
       kartlar.RehberReference.EntityKey = new System.Data.EntityKey("GenSatisModuleEntities.Rehber", "ID", RehberID);
       kartlar.KampanyaReference.EntityKey = new System.Data.EntityKey("GenSatisModuleEntities.Kampanya", "ID", KampanyaID);
       kartlar.BirimReference.EntityKey = new System.Data.EntityKey("GenSatisModuleEntities.Birim", "ID", BrimID);
       kartlar.Notlar = Notlar;
       genSatisCtx.AddToKartlar(kartlar);
       genSatisCtx.SaveChanges();
       List<Kartlar> kartAddedPatient;
       kartAddedPatient = (from k in genSatisCtx.Kartlar
                           where k.RehberReference.EntityKey == RehberID &&
                                 k.KampanyaReference.EntityKey == KampanyaID &&
                                 k.BirimReference.EntityKey == BrimID
                           select k)
   return kartAddedPatient ;
    }
}
```

How can I do that? I want to get data from Kartlar which data I added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
genSatisCtx.AddToKartlar(kartlar);
genSatisCtx.SaveChanges();
int newKartlarID = kartlar.KartID;//kartID or whatever you call your primary key
return newKartlarID;
```

after you save the object kartlar it gets a primary key that can be used afterwords hopefully this helps and also what language is kartlar????

Comment: Please give me some feedback I would like to see if this helps you or not

Comment: using (GenSatisModuleEntities genSatisCtx = new GenSatisModuleEntities())
            {
genSatisCtx. ObjectTrackingEnabled ----> not included Thanks...
}

Comment: programmist can you give me the entity you want it to ouptut and the other table structures that you have

Comment: i rearranged my question Laurece please look it sir :)

Comment: After Save event send KartId last one???? it is great if it is real. it must be magic

Comment: it is I know I have a previous question on this that I asked myself http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433333/scope-identity-with-linq
also hit me up with a selected answer if it works for you

Comment: ok; how to use write select statement wity EntityKey? i really want to learn!!! Laurance By the way i added you facebook ;)

Comment: Actually I am not to sure about entity keys I am not familiar with them at all so I am sorry I cant help you with that but I hope at least I solved your immediate problem with the newly created kartlar entity.

Comment: by the way Proggramist you might have added my father instead of me to your friends in facebook my name in facebook is larry burke

Comment: My Name is Yusuf Karatoprak : my msn : yusufkaratoprak@yahoo.com add me please

Comment: i don't find you facebook : larry burke i am Yusuf Karatoprak. if you searched me you can see me above page with beard ;)